# If then else to give 0 or 1 - VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement

I was wondering why this code does not print 1 at all. I know that 0 are overwriting the arr_bed variable. But, how I can make it distinguishable for the code to have both 0 and 1? Thanks!

```
 For n = 3 To time_frame + 3
            For i = 3 To 1002

                     If (Cells(i, "U").Value = Cells(n, "X").Value) Then
                     arr_bed = 1  ' admission (HH)
                     Else
                     arr_bed = 0

                    Cells(n, "Y").Value = arr_bed
                    End If
                    Next i

                    Next n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exit the for when it is found and move the output outside the inner loop:

```
For n = 3 To time_frame + 3
    arr_bed = 0
    For i = 3 To 1002
        If (Cells(i, "U").Value = Cells(n, "X").Value) Then
            arr_bed = 1
            Exit For ' admission (HH)
        End If
    Next i
    Cells(n, "Y").Value = arr_bed
Next n
```

Just another note:  You should qualify the sheets(without seeing the rest of the code I do not want to assume how to do this for you).

Comment: Scott. You have removed the else part which I needed to show both 0 and 1 in the output. I still have not reached to the goal of printing 1 when the statements is true 0 when it is false.

Comment: @Hamidkh no I did not, it is before the inner loop.  Did you try it?

Comment: Yes It did. It just gives me 1 not 0 is printed.

Comment: Then every value in column X exist in column U.  Is that not what you wanted, because that is what you are testing with a double loop like this?  It tests the value in X3 against every value in Column U, if found it puts a 1 in Y3, if none is found it puts a 0. Then it moves to X4 and tests that against every value in column U.  If you put the else back in and remove the `exit for` you are only getting the result of X3 vs. U1002 and you do not need the second loop as it will only return the last iteration of the inside loop.  More explanation may be required.

Comment: @Hamidkh are you trying to test only if X3=U3 and then put 1 or 0 in Y3?